# Iterate through a tree to check values

Tags: javascript

Trying to iterate through this tree (which I thought was an object at first) to console log the "products" key if the "stock_status" is false. Never done anything like this.

```
var m = {
    "option_labels": {
        "jamocha": {
            "configurable_product": {
                "small_image": null,
                "base_image": null
            },
            "products": ["12"],
            "stock_status": false
        },
        "matte white": {
            "configurable_product": {
                "small_image": null,
                "base_image": null
            },
            "products": ["13"],
            "stock_status": true
        },
        "cool gray": {
            "configurable_product": {
                "small_image": null,
                "base_image": null
            },
            "products": ["146"],
            "stock_status": true
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: @SLaks When is a nested object a tree and when is it just a nested object (on which you prefer to iterate over) ? Is there a rule of thumb? Maybe if the nested object is "unbalanced".

Comment: Oops; I completely misread the question (I thought you were looking for properties at an arbitrary depth).  Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `forEach` loop to check `stock_status`

```js
var m = {"option_labels":{"jamocha":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["12"],"stock_status":false},"matte white":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["13"],"stock_status":true},"cool gray":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["146"],"stock_status":true},"princess pink":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["147"],"stock_status":true},"key lime":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["148"],"stock_status":true},"nautical blue":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["149"],"stock_status":true},"slate":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["294"],"stock_status":true}}}

Object.keys(m.option_labels).forEach(function(e) {
  var option = m.option_labels[e];
  if(option.stock_status == false) console.log(option.products)
})
```

If you want to return just number not array you can change `console.log(option.products)` to `Number(option.products[0])`

```js
var m = {"option_labels":{"jamocha":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["12"],"stock_status":false},"matte white":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["13"],"stock_status":true},"cool gray":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["146"],"stock_status":true},"princess pink":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["147"],"stock_status":true},"key lime":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["148"],"stock_status":true},"nautical blue":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["149"],"stock_status":true},"slate":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["294"],"stock_status":true}}}

Object.keys(m.option_labels).forEach(function(e) {
  var option = m.option_labels[e];
  if(option.stock_status == false) console.log(Number(option.products[0]))
})
```

Comment: Why the imperative `forEach` and not the more functional `map`? Usually `forEach` is used to perform side effects on the receiving object, isn't it?

Comment: Not really, OP just want to `console.log` some properties if they match certain conditions, not to change anything, so in that case i would use `forEach`

Comment: Thank you very much! If you don't mind me asking how would you also log the main label with it, such as "jamocha"?

Comment: Just add key or  `e` in this case in forEach loop https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1030/

Answer (score 0):

You could use two nested loops for the keys of the objects and concatinate the result.

```js
var m = { "option_labels": { "jamocha": { "configurable_product": { "small_image": null, "base_image": null }, "products": ["12"], "stock_status": false }, "matte white": { "configurable_product": { "small_image": null, "base_image": null }, "products": ["13"], "stock_status": true }, "cool gray": { "configurable_product": { "small_image": null, "base_image": null }, "products": ["146"], "stock_status": true }, "princess pink": { "configurable_product": { "small_image": null, "base_image": null }, "products": ["147"], "stock_status": true }, "key lime": { "configurable_product": { "small_image": null, "base_image": null }, "products": ["148"], "stock_status": true }, "nautical blue": { "configurable_product": { "small_image": null, "base_image": null }, "products": ["149"], "stock_status": true }, "slate": { "configurable_product": { "small_image": null, "base_image": null }, "products": ["294"], "stock_status": true } } },
    products = [];

Object.keys(m).forEach(function (k) {
    Object.keys(m[k]).forEach(function (kk) {
        if (!m[k][kk].stock_status) {
            products = products.concat(m[k][kk].products);
        }
    });
});

console.log(products);
```

Comment: I think you'd better start from `m['option_labels']`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use lodash method [_.forOwnRight(object, [iteratee=_.identity])](https://lodash.com/docs#forOwnRight) to iterate over the object and method [_.concat(array, [values])](https://lodash.com/docs#concat) to get the concatenated array result:

```js
let m = {"option_labels":{"jamocha":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["12"],"stock_status":false},"matte white":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["13"],"stock_status":true},"cool gray":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["146"],"stock_status":true},"princess pink":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["147"],"stock_status":true},"key lime":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["148"],"stock_status":true},"nautical blue":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["149"],"stock_status":true},"slate":{"configurable_product":{"small_image":null,"base_image":null},"products":["294"],"stock_status":true}}},
    result = [];

_.forOwnRight(m.option_labels, (v, k) => {
    if (!v.stock_status) {
        result = _.concat(result, v.products);
    }
});

// array result
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.js"></script>
```